# display more than 8 div classes

Tags: php, javascript, css, jquery

I have got a problem with the code in my PHP. I stored 8 rows of channels in mysql database and I use var totalrowcount to display 8 boxes for div classes to display with rows that I stored from mysql, but I cannot be able to display more than 8 boxes of div classes when I store more than 8 rows in mysql.

I want to create the unlimited boxes for div classes with any range of number to match the rows depends on how many rows that I store in mysql database.

Here is the code I found where the trouble is coming from:

```
    var totalrowcount = 8;
<div class="mainWrap">
    <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div id="image1" class="channelList div_1_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe1" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_2"></div>
            <div id="programe2" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_3"></div>
            <div id="programe3" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row"  id="row2">
        <div id="image2" class="channelList div_2_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe4" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_2"></div>
            <div id="programe5" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_3"></div>
            <div id="programe6" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row"  id="row3">
        <div id="image3" class="channelList div_3_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe7" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_2"></div>
            <div id="programe8" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_3"></div>
            <div id="programe9" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_4"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row"  id="row4">
        <div id="image4" class="channelList div_4_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe10" class="pgmFirstRow div_4_2"></div>
            <div id="programe11" class="pgmFirstRow div_4_3"></div>
            <div id="programe12" class="pgmFirstRow div_4_4"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row"  id="row5">
        <div id="image5" class="channelList div_5_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe13" class="pgmFirstRow div_5_2"></div>
            <div id="programe14" class="pgmFirstRow div_5_3"></div>
            <div id="programe15" class="pgmFirstRow div_5_4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row" id="row6">
        <div id="image6" class="channelList div_6_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe16" class="pgmFirstRow div_6_2"></div>
            <div id="programe17" class="pgmFirstRow div_6_3"></div>
            <div id="programe18" class="pgmFirstRow div_6_4"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="row"  id="row7">
        <div id="image7" class="channelList div_7_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe19" class="pgmFirstRow div_7_2"></div>
            <div id="programe20" class="pgmFirstRow div_7_3"></div>
            <div id="programe21" class="pgmFirstRow div_7_4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="row"  id="row8">
        <div id="image8" class="channelList div_8_1"></div>
        <div class="rowSubPgm">
            <div id="programe22" class="pgmFirstRow div_8_2"></div>
            <div id="programe23" class="pgmFirstRow div_8_3"></div>
            <div id="programe24" class="pgmFirstRow div_8_4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

I can output the unlimited rows from mysql without have any problem, but I cannot display more than 8 boxes for div classes. If I want to create the classes, I would have to change the last number in each line at the end, e.g: pgmFirstRow div_9_4, pgmFirstRow div_10_4 and so on.

I am going to store thousand of rows in mysql and I find that it would be too much for me to work it on to add thousand lines of codes for add div classes.

Does anyone know how to create the code to allow me to add unlimited number of div classes using with the arrays for the totalrowcount to match the rows that I store in mysql to allow me to add any range of boxes for div classes??

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: why are you adding individual classes?

Comment: Why would you want to create a class for every row/column pair? I think you might be approaching this in a more difficult way than is necessary.

Comment: @nderscore yeah he is doing it in the most difficult way he could..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats why they invented the `for` and `while` loops. You can continue to print `div`s and rows until you reach the end by using a loop.

`PDO` example:

```
$query = $con->prepare("/* Your QUERY*/");
try {
// Try to execute the query
$query->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
// Error jumps here
echo $e->getMessage();
}
// Set fetch mode so we can retrieve the data by an object
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while($row = $query->fetch()){
/* While there are rows available we continue executing this loop */
/* You can get data using $row->id for example */
echo 
"<div class=\"clear\"></div>
<div class=\"row\"  id=\"row".$row->id."\">
    <div id=\"image".$row->id."\" class=\"channelList div_".$row->id."_1\"></div>
    <div class=\"rowSubPgm\">
        <div id=\"programe".$row->id."\" class=\"pgmFirstRow div_".$row->id."_2\"></div>
        <div id=\"programe".$row->id."\" class=\"pgmFirstRow div_".$row->id."_3\"></div>
        <div id=\"programe".$row->id."\" class=\"pgmFirstRow div_".$row->id."_4\"></div>
    </div>";
}
```

`mysql_*` example. ( I don't recommend using this one. I just wrote it for you in the case you're more familiar with this rather than PDO. Switching to PDO is always a good idea.

```
// Assuming you already executed the query
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// Here it's pretty much the same as PDO. Only now the $row is an array instead of an object
echo
    "<div class=\"clear\"></div>
    <div class=\"row\"  id=\"row".$row['id']."\">
    <div id=\"image".$row['id']."\" class=\"channelList div_".$row['id']."_1\"></div>
    <div class=\"rowSubPgm\">
        <div id=\"programe".$row['id']."\" class=\"pgmFirstRow div_".$row['id']."_2\"></div>
        <div id=\"programe".$row['id']."\" class=\"pgmFirstRow div_".$row['id']."_3\"></div>
        <div id=\"programe".$row['id']."\" class=\"pgmFirstRow div_".$row['id']."_4\"></div>
    </div>";
}
```

**EDIT:**

By the way I won't suggest displaying all the rows at the same time. Imagine your rows grow to thousands and over and you want to print a thousand of records. I bet both mysql server and the browser will be upset about the fact :) Instead try paginating your rows.

Comment: thanks for your help miro, do you know how to count on each tag of span id like <p id='channels'> from my other script get-listing.php before i create the rows?? thanks!!!